# Outlook changes & to &amp;

Tags: c#, asp-classic, hyperlink, outlook, html-encode

I habe an ASP website, and I want to send an EMail using a Template.
In the template i have two placeholders inside an `<a href="">` *(%CODE% and %EMAIL%)* they are supposed to be query strings

it looks kinda like this

`<a href="http://www.foo.com?qs1=example&Code=%CODE%&Email=%EMAIL%" />`

I use the `.Replacement()` Method to replace the two fields.

The Problem is that after receiving the email, the & characters are replaced by `&amp;` and the the query string becomes invalid.

I don't know if this is a Outlook Problem (2013) or if it can be fixed within the code.

Thanks

Comment: what code are you referring to?

Comment: C# if it's what you meen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ampersands aren't valid in this context.

If you "encode" them yourself before Outlook can.. it will switch it back to normal for you:

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com?qs1=example&amp;Code=%CODE%&amp;Email=%EMAIL%" />
```

So **you** use `amp;`, and Outlook will fix it. Browsers do the same thing.

Even if it doesn't look like it in the page source.. if you click the link the `amp;` will be replaced with a normal ampersand.